# IntelliTrace with Console and Trace Events

Tags: events, console, trace, intellitrace

I'm using Intellitrace, in the Options for IntelliTrace I added the Console and Trace events, because in my code I have some Console.Write and Trace.Write calls that i would like to see, then I run my application in debug mode, but when I inspect the events raised by my application in the IntelliTrace window , none of this events were shown, but yes others events. Even, I go step by step in the code that has the line with the Trace.Write call, but nothing, the call or the event  does not appears in the IntelliTrace windows.

What's i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have done anything wrong. I would expect everything to work correctly based on your description. I would like to work with you to resolve the problem that you are having.  Feel free to contact me directly my email address is larrygug.  I work for Microsoft on the IntelliTrace team. You should be able to figure out my entire email address.

Once we have determined what went wrong I will post the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a try using the Console.WriteLine() and Trace.WriteLine instead of the "Write", and see whether the events are collected?

Note that IntelliTrace does not collect all the Console and Trace event even if you check these categories in IntelliTrace configuration page. If you expand these categories in configration, you'll see the exact function signatures collected by IntelliTrace. A more precise description of the functions can be found in the collection plan, which locates at %Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\11.0.0\en\collectionplan.xml" for Visual Studio 2012 if you choose to install to the default location.